# gnu radio Index Error: output_index must be < noutputs

Tags: selector, gnuradio

I am using a gnu radio flowgraph to attempt to select the appropriate Selector Block output as explained below. The following error occurs when I run the flowgraph:
Index Error: output_index must be < noutputs.

Obviously the chosen index of 1 is less than the number of outputs 2. What is wrong?

The following code is in an FT8_Receive hier block. It shows only the code pertinent to the issue I am experiencing. The connections section shows the Selector Block with 2 outputs connected to 2 Wave File Sinks. I am attempting to select the appropriate output by using wave_select in the output index as shown in def set_wave_select().

```
 class FT8_Receive(gr.hier_block2):
    def __init__(self, wave_select=0):
        gr.hier_block2.__init__(
            self, "FT8_Receive",
                gr.io_signature(1, 1, gr.sizeof_float*1),
                gr.io_signature(0, 0, 0),
    )

    ##################################################
    # Parameters
    ##################################################
    self.wave_select = wave_select
    
    ##################################################
    # Connections
    ##################################################
    self.connect((self.blocks_selector_0, 1), (self.blocks_wavfile_sink_0_0, 0))
    self.connect((self.blocks_selector_0, 0), (self.blocks_wavfile_sink_0_0_0, 0))
    self.connect((self, 0), (self.rational_resampler_xxx_0, 0))
    self.connect((self.rational_resampler_xxx_0, 0), (self.blocks_selector_0, 0))
```

.................................

```
    def get_wave_select(self):
        return self.wave_select

    def set_wave_select(self, wave_select):
        self.wave_select = wave_select
        self.blocks_selector_0.set_output_index(self.wave_select)
```

The following code is from the .py file that is an OOT in the top block of the flowgraph. This is where I am calling set_wave_select.

from FT8_Receive import FT8_Receive

```
RCV = FT8_Receive()
wave_select = 1
RCV.set_wave_select(wave_select)
```

All is explained above.